# Printing UTF-8 Encoded Text in EPSON TM-T88IV Thermal Printer

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, thermal-printer, epson

I have used the instruction below to print via .net for EPSON TM-T88IV Thermal Printer.

http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/12/sending-a-bit-image-to-an-epson-tm-t88iii-receipt-printer-using-c-and-escpos/

I'm using below code, I have changed the encoding to UTF-8 but still can't print Unicode.
Some junk characters are printed.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Print(PrinterName, GetDocument());
    }

    private const string PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T88IV ReceiptE4";

    private static byte[] GetDocument()
    {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms,Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            // Reset the printer bws (NV images are not cleared)
            bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.Escape);
            bw.Write("سلام دنیا");
            bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.Newline);
            // Feed 3 vertical motion units and cut the paper with a 1 point cut
            bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.GroupSeparator);
            bw.Write('V');
            bw.Write((byte)66);
            bw.Write((byte)3);

            bw.Flush();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static void Print(string printerName, byte[] document)
    {
        NativeMethods.DOC_INFO_1 documentInfo;
        IntPtr printerHandle;

        documentInfo = new NativeMethods.DOC_INFO_1();
        documentInfo.pDataType = "RAW";
        documentInfo.pDocName = "Bit Image Test";

        printerHandle = new IntPtr(0);

        if (NativeMethods.OpenPrinter(printerName.Normalize(), out printerHandle, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (NativeMethods.StartDocPrinter(printerHandle, 1, documentInfo))
            {
                int bytesWritten;
                byte[] managedData;
                IntPtr unmanagedData;

                managedData = document;
                unmanagedData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(managedData.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(managedData, 0, unmanagedData, managedData.Length);

                if (NativeMethods.StartPagePrinter(printerHandle))
                {
                    NativeMethods.WritePrinter(
                        printerHandle,
                        unmanagedData,
                        managedData.Length,
                        out bytesWritten);
                    NativeMethods.EndPagePrinter(printerHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                }

                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(unmanagedData);

                NativeMethods.EndDocPrinter(printerHandle);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }

            NativeMethods.ClosePrinter(printerHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: not unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I have an EPSON TM-T88V and from [here](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=337) I understand both of them do **NOT** support UTF-8.

The only options are these ASCII encodings:
(taken from [here](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32))

for TM-T88IV I find them to be:

[South Asia models]

- Page  0 [PC437: USA, Standard Europe]
- Page 20 [Thai Character Code 42]
- Page 21 [Thai Character Code 11]
- Page 26 [Thai Character Code 18]
- Page 30 [TCVN-3: Vietnamese]
- Page 31 [TCVN-3: Vietnamese]

[Other models]

- Page 0 [PC437: USA, Standard Europe]
- Page 1 [Katakana]
- Page 2 [PC850: Multilingual]
- Page 3 [PC860: Portuguese]
- Page 4 [PC863: Canadian-French]
- Page 5 [PC865: Nordic]
- Page 16 [WPC1252]
- Page 17 [PC866: Cyrillic #2]
- Page 18 [PC852: Latin 2]
- Page 19 [PC858: Euro]
  (Page 255 is a space page.)